# Using SystemDialogInput in a Manipulate expression

Tags: dialog-window, user-interface

I want to add the select directory function in a user interface such as:

```
Manipulate[
  Graphics[],
    {{dir,""}, ControlType -> None},
     Button["Select     Directory", 
       dir = SystemDialogInput["Directory"], Method -> "Queued"]]
```

When I ran it, *Mathematica* aborted the Kernel.

Comment: works fine in Version 9 (windows 10).

Answer (score 1):

I can not reproduce your problem. I tried the following slightly modified version of your code and it worked fine. I evaluated it in V10.4.1 running under OS X 1.10.2.

```
Manipulate[
  dir,
  {{dir, ""}, None},
  Button["Select Directory",
    dir = SystemDialogInput["Directory"],
    Method -> "Queued"]]
```

[image: demo]

I evaluated the code in new notebook with clean kernel. I suggest you try it that way.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I guess this problem is just due to the version of Mathematica. Mine is  V10.3.1